# Compression algorithms for small strings - building upon / extending Huffman

Tags: data-compression, huffman-coding

I'm exploring algorithms to compress small strings like the following - every line is to be compressed individually, i.e. even those small strings should get compressed:

```
ZYXH1|104932,104932,927.6000,200,1,927.4000,1600,1
ZYXH1|104932,104932,3390,1600,1,3389,2700,1
HXDFF|0001739.42;HXDFF:Y|0U010:49:32
ZYXH1|104932,104932,5360,5400,1,5350,16400,1
ZYXH1|104931,104931,1966,2800,1,1965,3800,1;HXYFBR|0003.12;HXCFBR|0001.14;HXCFER|0006.7;HXMKCF|0003268409320112.0
ZYXH1|104932,104932,526,192400,1,525,88400,1
ZYXH1|104932,104932,803,6300,1,802,63900,1
ZYXDFF|803;ZYXDFF:Y|104932;ZYXVW|100800.6381;ZYXVL|1121700,104932;TAXTIC|L719;TAXNO|L1121700
ZYXH1|104932,104932,1367,2100,1,1366.5000,2800,1
HXYFBR|0002.04;HXCFBR|0001.52;HXCFER|00015.0;HXMKCF|0001676300748887.4
ZYXH1|104932,104932,380,63500,1,379,21500,1
ZYXH1|104932,104932,5360,5400,1,5350,16400,1
ZYXH1|104932,104932,803,3900,1,802,63800,1;ZYXVA|898075800
ZYXH1|104932,104932,3045,4700,1,3040,5500,1;ZYXDFF|3040;ZYXDFF:Y|104932;ZYXVW|1003043.4356;ZYXVL|164600,104932;ZYXVA|498213500;TAXTIC|L199;TAXTICD|L42;TAXNO|L164600;TAXDFG|Y0058
ZYXDFF|3040;ZYXDFF:Y|104932;ZYXVW|1003043.3304;ZYXVL|169800,104932;TAXTIC|L202;TAXNO|L169800
ZYXDFF|3040;ZYXDFF:Y|104932;ZYXVW|1003043.2935;ZYXVL|171700,104932;TAXTIC|L206;TAXNO|L171700
ZYXDFF|3040;ZYXDFF:Y|104932;ZYXVW|1003043.2764;ZYXVL|172600,104932;HXCFF|0003040;HXCFF:T|0T010:49;TAXTIC|L212;TAXNO|L172600
ZYXDFF|3040;ZYXDFF:Y|104932;ZYXVW|1003043.2745;ZYXVL|172700,104932;TAXTIC|L213;TAXNO|L172700
ZYXH1|104932,104932,4168,1200,1,4167,100,1
```

I have a couple of megabytes worth of data like the above, which allows me to create a static statistical model, i.e. for Huffman. If I have such a static model, I can embed that with the decompressor, removing the need to transmit/store it, i.e. trading compression rate for adaptability (important with these small strings).

I have now tried various algorithms, and the results of compressing those megabytes worth of strings (using a simple program that transmits the compressed data via TCP) are as follows:

```
 Algorithm       Rate  Bytes/sec
--------------------------------
 deflate optim   46.7%    3724917
 deflate fast    44.2%    3831672
 huffman         41.9%   11169462
 lz4 1576 optim  25.6%    4334541
 lz4 18576 fast  23.5%   42504338
 lz4 1576 fast   23.4%   70996590
 uncompressed       0%  105210881
```

So deflate is at the top of the list when it comes to the compression rate, (even for these small strings, where deflate does not rely on a shared static model) but it's 2 to 3 times slower than (my home-grown) Huffman coder. Given all the repeating character patterns in the input data, it would seem one could do much better than the Huffman coder which only looks at single bytes. LZ4 can be really fast with small buffer sizes (I only listed sizes of 1576 and 18576, Bytes/sec for bigger sizes drops significantly), but compression rate is not that good.

Are there simple ways to change / extend a per-byte Huffman coder to make use of the fact that there are many repeating (multi-byte) character patterns?

But it shouldn't grow the statistical model to thousands of entries (currently the model has at most 256 symbols, and merely [changing from 1-grams to 2-grams](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/98804/95225) would increase it to up to 32768), because in fact I do want to change and hence store/transmit the statistical model, but not for every string, but only every, say, 1 megabyte or so. So it would be somewhere between a static statistical model and a fully dynamic statistical model.

Comment: Trying to build a model based on Huffman on a set of upto 32768 characters would have too much entropy and defeat the purpose.  I use delta coding for Unicode.

Comment: @arun I will take a look at delta coding... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A simple variant of Huffman is due, I believe, to David Wheeler.

Suppose the alphabet is $\Sigma = \{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$ and let $\star$ be some new character that's not in $\Sigma$. For each character $s\in\Sigma$, let $p(s)$ be the most common character to occur immediately after $s$ in your dataset.

To compress the string $X=x_1\dots x_N$, you first scan through it and, each time $x_{i+1}=p(x_i)$, replace $x_{i+1}$ with $\star$, giving a new string over alphabet $\Sigma\cup\{{\star}\}$. Then run ordinary Huffman on the resulting string. The idea is that the character $\star$ should be really common in the modified string, so it should get a really short codeword.

For example, if your alphabet is $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $p(a)=a$, $p(b)=a$, $p(c)=d$ and $p(d)=c$, then the string $abacd$ would be transformed to $ab{\star}c{\star}$ and $cdcdcd$ would be transformed to $c{\star}{\star}{\star}{\star}{\star}$.

Since all your example strings begin with `Z`, it might also be worth storing the most common initial character to allow you to replace the first character of the string with $\star$, too.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting variant - does it have a name? For figuring out *p(s)* for all *s* I would have to maintain a table of up to *n^2* entries. The good news is I'd only have to store/transmit the result of that analysis, which would be an addition of 256 bytes, in my case. Will have to think though how to make it efficient, as I intend to calculate this "on-line", i.e. while encoding - perhaps not analyzing every encoding, but only sampling every 100th encoding or so, which should give sufficient results.

Comment: I've heard it referred to as "Wheelerized Huffman", but Google hasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these libraries for compressing short strings:

https://github.com/siara-cc/unishox :

**Unishox** is a hybrid encoder (entropy, dictionary and delta coding). It works by assigning fixed prefix-free codes for each letter of the 95 letter printable Character Set (entropy coding). It encodes repeating letter sets separately (dictionary coding). For Unicode characters (UTF-8), delta coding is used.  It also has special handling for repeating upper case and num pad characters.

Unishox was developed to save memory in embedded devices and compress strings stored in databases.  It is used in [many projects](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox#projects-that-use-unishox) and has an [extension for Sqlite](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox_Sqlite_UDF) database.  Although it is slower than other available libraries, it works well for the given applications.

https://github.com/antirez/smaz :

**Smaz** was developed by Salvatore Sanfilipo and it compresses strings by replacing parts of it using a codebook. This was the first one available for compressing short strings as far as I know.

https://github.com/Ed-von-Schleck/shoco :

**shoco** was written by Christian Schramm. It is an entropy encoder, because the length of the representation of a character is determined by the probability of encountering it in a given input string.

It has a default model for English language and a provision to train new models based on given sample text.

PS: The first one was developed by me and its working principle is explained in [this article](https://github.com/siara-cc/Unishox/blob/master/Unishox_Article_1.pdf?raw=true):

Comparison:
I compressed the first line of your data and posted the screenshot below:

[image]

I also compressed the whole text using Unishox and it gives a savings of 47.8%:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting. Would you care to expand your answer and briefly explain the algorithms used for the 3 links, including your own one?

Comment: I think I have done better than that.  If you have more questions, just let me know.

Comment: Much more useful now - thanks! But note the ` every line is to be compressed individually` in my question. So my figures show the average compression ratio of compressing all lines individually, and I haven't looked into delta coding yet, so I don't know if that makes a difference with Unishox or not.

Comment: Yes, Unishox is specifically built for short strings and can compress each line individually. For instance, "Hello World" compresses to 9 bytes, without need for statistical model.  But it is much slower than deflate or huffman because it uses multiple methods.